# C++ - Efficient approach to initializing structure

Tags: c++, initialization

A colleague and I were debating the efficiency of certain approaches to zero'ing out a `struct`. Let's assume we have a simple `struct` like so:

```
struct {
  int     iMyInt;
  char    cMyChar;
  double  dCoordinates[128];
} s_t;
```

My approach would be to do this:

```
s_t myStruct = { 0 };
```

My colleague advised this approach instead:

```
s_t myStruct = { };
```

He noted that my approach initializes a single element, and then the rest of the elements, in a two-part operation, while his approach initializes the entire `struct` in a one-part operation that is faster and more efficient.

Is this true, and if so, is it always the case across all compiler optimization levels (ie: does the compiler figure this out and optimize it for me anyways)?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you compare the generated assembly? I'll be surprised if it's not the same. Modern compilers optimize, you know. Do it in Release build, of course.

Comment: To be honest that code is invalid.. you're declaring an object instead of a s_t structure type..

Comment: @Deduplicator `s_t` is an object, not a type.

Comment: If there is any difference for some compiler, I would be really surprised. And would not trust that compiler to do an acceptable job on any other C++-code as well.

Comment: your missing typedef there, and your struct is not public: typedef struct { .. } s_t; and do disassemble the code as stated by others.

Comment: @Stígandr The `typedef` syntax is quite unusual in C++. As for the `public` comment, what does that even mean?

Comment: @Stígandr that's not a class, you don't need `public`

Comment: @juanchopanza +1 I was wrong there I didn't manage to edit it out >.< because the time ran out. With the public statement I mean, it was wrong. Sorry about that. (Distractions around me here atm you see :) )

Comment: Although it is not faster, I prefer the second approach for simplicity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the code you posted is invalid: you should declare that structure type as follows

```
struct s_t {
  int     iMyInt;
  char    cMyChar;
  double  dCoordinates[128];
};
```

That said: in your specific case the two approaches are the same and everything is zeroe'd out. At `-O3` and even `-O0` for clang **there are no differences** for a generic test code which uses any of the above members and/or array elements (at `-O0` it even calls `memset` on the entire structure in both cases).

```
s_t obj = {0};

movq    %rcx, %rdi
movl    %eax, %esi
callq   memset

s_t obj = {};

movq    %rcx, %rdi
movl    %eax, %esi
callq   memset
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11 §8.5.1/7:

> **“** If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member
>   not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list

And last dash of C++11 §8.5.4/3:

> **“**  Otherwise [*i.e. T is not a class, not an aggregate, and not a reference*], if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

Value-initialized for a simple type like `int` means zero-initialized.

So the formal effect of `{0}`, for a type that has `0` value, is the same as the formal effect of `{}`.

The standard can however not dictate the **Quality of Implementation** of a compiler. A compiler might react to what it considers bad words in a file name, and just to spite you generate time consuming dummy code before each function call. Likewise it just might, in theory, treat the two notations differently wrt. code generation, even though they mean the same.

---

Re your colleague’s idea that

> **“** He noted that my approach initializes a single element, and then the rest of the elements, in a two-part operation, while his approach initializes the entire struct in a one-part operation that is faster and more efficient.

No, that’s just an incorrect vision of how a compiler might work.

Compilers don’t work that way.

But the empty braces notation has the advantage that it also works with e.g. `std::string` and any other type `T` where `T()` is a valid expression, but `T(0)` is not.

I.e. it’s slightly more general.

---

All this said, note that in C++ it’s not necessary to do the C acrobatics

```
typedef struct Point_tag
{
    int x, y;
} Point;
```

Instead you can simply do

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};
```

Comment: I dont get your last point (about the structure declaration with/without typedef). The latter is a perfectly sane C code snippet.

Comment: @Rerito it's valid but you need to drag the `struct` prefix everywhere you need to reference the type - in contrast to C++.

Comment: @icepack : Of course you do. It is used in the Linux Kernel coding standard (No typedef). It makes clear what you are manipulating I see no harm in that :)